# How to set up Paypal on WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

I've already tried hard to set up Paypal on WooCommerce without success.

I wonder what is the actual steps used to set up PayPal on WooCommerce?

My problems are:

1. I tested it with my sandbox but, after payment, it doesn't redirect back from PayPal to my website. (I've already had business Paypal account and the redirect url on Paypal is already set)
2. The order status after check out is still 'pending'(unpaid).
   It doesn't automatically change the status after check out.
   I've no idea how to make it work?
3. What the difference between 'PayPal Email' and 'Receiver Email' in payment gateway setting?
4. Do I have to do anything to make IPN work?
5. No notification email sent to shop owner...

NOTE: On my status `page -> wp_remote_post()` was successful - PayPal IPN is working.

Thanks in advance for any helps!

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/woocommerce/

Comment: Here's the documentation. It helped me a lot. http://docs.woothemes.com/document/paypal-standard/

Comment: Take a look at my [PayPal for WooCommerce](http://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/) plugin. It's free and it'll get PayPal working correctly on your site very quickly and easily.

Comment: Are you doing this on localhost or on an actual server?

Comment: One of the problems is that to use the sandbox you have to have a sandbox set up and actually be logged in to it. You may want to try buying a 1 cent product "live".

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like part 3 might be your issue. In the [IPN debugging section of the documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/paypal-standard/#section-6) it has the following:

> #### Check Email Addresses
>
> Check the Email Address (in the paypal gateway settings) matches the
>   email address passed back by IPN. You should be using your primary
>   email address for your paypal account. Failure to do so will mean the
>   IPN response will be rejected.

Answer (score -1):

This might be due to the IPN not communicating correctly with your WooCommerce site. Since wp_remote_post() is successful, it suggests that IPN is working. Ensure the WooCommerce IPN handler URL is correctly set in your PayPal IPN settings. Sometimes, other plugins can interfere with how WooCommerce handles payments. Check with disabling all the plugins else contact support